# Bull: Cannot define a handler more than once per Queue instance

Tags: node.js, bull.js

I'm using [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) with node.js. I was thinking of using a master-slave model, where one thread puts stuff in the queue, and another just pulls it from the queue.

However, when my worker threads try to pull from the queue, they get this error:

> Error: Cannot define a handler more than once per Queue instance

when I call this function

```
var doJobs = function() {
    return Queue.process(job, jobDone) {
        console.log("job done");
        jobDone();
    });
}
```

Can anyone tell me what this error means?

Comment: Umn, I think your code above is wrong...  Also, it seems like you're calling doJobs multiple times... you probably only need to assign the handler once, and it will just send one job to that handler at a time.

Comment: What does it mean to assign the handler exactly? I'm having trouble understanding this terminology

Comment: Also I am calling it more than once. I'm calling it once per thread.

Comment: @Gakho node.js is single threaded, so what does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

The doJobs function was being hit multiple times. I thought this was correct, in reality, you only need to hit it once.

Answer (score 1):

[`queue.process(job => {/* ... */})`](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/HEAD/REFERENCE.md#queueprocess) registers a processing handler for a queue that describes *how* a job should be performed. It doesn't actually trigger a job to be performed on the spot as you may think.

The error prevents you from redefining or mistakenly adding additional processing handlers -- a job can only have one way to be processed.

When you add jobs to the queue with [`queue.add()`](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/HEAD/REFERENCE.md#queueadd), the handler you've previously registered by passing to `queue.process` is applied to the job, producing a result that can be accessed with [`await job.finished()`](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/HEAD/REFERENCE.md#jobfinished), [`queue.on("completed", (job, result) => {/* ... */})`](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/HEAD/REFERENCE.md#events) or a [completion queue](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/PATTERNS.md#returning-job-completions), for example.

By the way, your "master-slave model" is actually a producer-consumer model. Master-slave is when the slave is under the full control of the master, but in producer-consumer, the consumer doesn't have to do anything and isn't typically under the control of the producer at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue using Bull in NestJs. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues

The exact error was:

> (node:12887) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot define the same handler twice **default**

I was using the same name for different processors (consumers). So, they were more than one processor for a Bull queue.

My copy/paste mistake !

Once I defined different names for each processor and queue, everything was fixed.